# Dynamic style css font-size ngFor angular 4 ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ngfor

I searched on many forums and I still don't find the solution how to dynamically change the font-size in a *ngFor loop..

---

### home.html

```
<span *ngFor="let quality of qualities | async">
    <button  [ngStyle]="{'font-size': quality.$key + 'px'}">{{quality.$key}} 
      : {{quality.$value}}</button>
</span>
```

### home.ts

```
qualities :FirebaseListObservable<any>;
```

### Here is a picture of what is displayed :

[image]

I want to style font-size as big as the number next to the word. For example : clever : 200 should have a size of 200px.

### When I inspect html I get :

```
<button ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]">intelligent : 5</button>
```

### console.log(qualities) and each quality

[image]

So there must be a problem with quality in the ngFor, but I don't know what

Thank you for your help !

Comment: @MohanGopi I get this error : ``Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 14 in [{'font-size': {{quality.$key}} + 'px'}] in ...``

Comment: @MohanGopi Done, thanks for you help by the way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're passing the `key` instead of the `value`, it's interpreting this as `font-size: cleverpx`.

Try:

```
<span *ngFor="let quality of qualities | async">
  <button  [ngStyle]="{'font-size': quality.$value + 'px'}">{{quality.$key}} 
      : {{quality.$value}}</button>
</span>
```